# Не запускается ReactJS на Apache (Ubuntu)

Tags: reactjs, apache, apache2, vds

На своём пк я сбилдил приложение ReactJs командой `npm run build`, затем мне высветилось сообщение об успешном билде и такое сообщение:

```
You may serve it with a static server:

  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
```

Если я пишу эти команды, то сбилженное приложение прекрасно запускается у меня на компьютере, но когда я перекидываю этот билд на VDS, под управлением Ubuntu и за сторону сервера отвечает Apache, то при попытке загрузить сайт в консоль сайта пишется ошибка:

```
main.d74030ae.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2.267f33d3.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.84a11725.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2.267f33d3.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.84a11725.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.d74030ae.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

и сайт полностью белый

Что делать?

Comment: а вы файлы то скинули в апач, на которые ругается с ошибкой 404?

Comment: У Вас после выполнения `build` должна была появится директория build или dist, и в ней собранный проект. Вот все с этой директории нужно было перенести в корневую директорию сервера

Comment: Появилась папка build, затем всю эту папку я перенёс на apache в var/www/html
И вышло, что сайт стал доступен по Пути host/build/index.html (это в интернете)

Comment: Нужно иметнно в корень апача кидать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании `create react app` по умолчанию приложение рассчитано на запуск из корневой папки. Для запуска из другой папки нужно добавить в `package.json` параметр `homepage`:

```
"homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/relativepath",
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А если у сайта есть ssl сертификат, то сертификат никак не помешает?

Comment: И ещё вопрос, это нужно указывать перед командой ```npm run build``` ?

Comment: Да, перед тем как выполнить `npm run build`

Comment: ssl на сервере тут не участвует, так как эта настройка относится только к путям к файлам в билде